# Web Browser sound is too low. Everything else works fine

Tags: windows-7, audio, internet, browser

As the title says, audio on my PC is working fine.  However, web browsers audio is too low (tried Chrome, IE, and Firefox).

Here is what I've verified:
 1.  Multiple web browsers to rule out a specific one.  The audio is too low on all of them.
 2.  Mixer settings:  I have ensured that the audio for the web application is not turned down.
 3.  I have tested my headphones on another PC that works just fine.
 4.  Audio from CD, MP3's, or desktop applications and windows sounds are all fine.
 5.  I have re-installed flash, just in case it was a flash problem, but it is still bad.
 6.  Audio on Youtube is all the way up.
 7.  Audio on my PC (when all the way up) is still too soft.

Here is an example of a video that I can barely hear on Youtube (Random C++ Win32 API video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JSGDclK39w

I watched the same video on another PC with the audio perfectly fine.

What am I missing?!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using Windows 7 64-Bit.
Audio Driver:  Realtek HD Audio (Version 6.0.1.7246 from 5/14/2014).  This is the latest I've found.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: No answer here yet: just some ideas/questions here...  Try audio in flash other than a video.  e.g., homestarrunner.com.  My hunch is this problem is probably a setting related to flash.  Re-installing flash might not have purged old settings.  That would explain consistency between all browsers.  Or, maybe not flash... maybe Silverlight?  If you can log in with a friend's Netflix account or Amazon Prime account, how is the volume there?  You might have multiple logical devices for sound output, and most programs use the default.  What sound output devices are on your system?

Comment: Edited to show my Audio Driver. I'll see if I can test audio from another source that uses Silverlight etc.

Comment: Silverlight Audio from here seems fine.  Looks like it's getting narrowed down to some specific type of video.  http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/iis-smooth-streaming/demo/#/on-demand

Comment: HTML5 video/audio here work fine:  http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html